# Bootstrap 3 Modal behaving badly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to slowly integrate Bootstrap 3 into an existing site (running on .NET 4.5 MVC, FWIW). I developing a page with a modal; it will container a contact form, and eventually I hope to be able to call it from other pages as well.

The problem right now is that the modal will not close properly. When clicking on the Close button, the semitransparent background layer disappears and the modal slides up and off the page--but the modal then snaps right back into centered position in the viewport.  }:-(

Code for your consideration... in the <head> of the page we are calling...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/parallax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.hoverintent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cluetip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mosaic.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-grids.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-modal.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/CommCtr.min.css" />
```

Then, the modal itself is created like so:

```
<div id="modalFinder" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Please complete the form.</h3>
            </div>
            <article id="modalFinderEmailForm" class="modal-body container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="col-md-12 container-fluid" id="FinderEmailForm" name="FinderEmailForm" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="FirstName">First Name<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
                            </p>
                            <p class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="LastName">Last Name<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="text" id="LastName" />
                            </p>
                        </div>

            more code...

                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="col-md-12" style="text-align: right;">
                                <input type="hidden" id="destinationEmail" name="destinationEmail" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="destinationBcc" name="destinationBcc" value="comments@example.com" />
                                <button type="button" id="btnFinderSubmit">Submit</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One thing that I may have done wrong is to try and include out only the relevant CSS for the task at hand (that's what `bootstrap-grids.min.css` and `bootstrap-modal.min.css` are about), and I certainly may have missed a key piece. I AM trying to do all this using the Bootstrap CSS; is there some JS I need as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You definitely need the bootstrap JS as well to have working modals!

Comment: <facepalm />  Yes, I discovered that immediately after posting. I'm still not able to remove the modal though; it still slides up, then snaps back into place. Wondering if maybe I have some CSS class name conflicts...  any other ideas?

Comment: I guess so. If you say the modal opened even before you included the Bootstrap Modal JS, then there might be a conflict somewhere most likely..